# Gitlab post-receive hook Host key verification failed

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, git-post-receive

I'm having 3 servers:

```
werkstation.example.com -> server where the gitlab repository is cloned & for changing the files fom the repository
git.example.com -> gitab server with repository "tomcat"
docker.example.com -> server where the files will be copied with git hook
```

My git hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

read oldrev newrev refname

REPO="git@git.example.com:michaelv1234/tomcat.git"
BRANCH=`echo $refname | sed -n 's/^refs\/heads\///p'`
BRANCH_DIR="/home/michael"
SSH_DEST="michael@docker.example.com"

##
# Instantiate the branches on the puppetmaster
if [ "$newrev" -eq 0 ] 2> /dev/null; then
        # branch is being deleted
        echo "Deleting remote branch $SSH_DEST $BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH"
        echo "$SSH_DEST" /bin/sh
        ssh  "$SSH_DEST" /bin/sh <<-EOF
                cd "$BRANCH_DIR" && rm -rf $BRANCH
        EOF
else
        # branch is being updated
        echo "Updating remote branch $SSH_DEST $BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH"
        ssh "$SSH_DEST" /bin/sh <<-EOF
                { cd "$BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH" || mkdir -p "$BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH" && cd "$BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH"; } \
                && { git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/$BRANCH || { git clone "$REPO" ./ && git checkout $BRANCH; }; }
        EOF
fi
```

But i'm still receiving this error:

```
michael@werkstation:~/tomcat$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 254 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Updating remote branch michael@docker.example.com /home/michael/master
remote: Host key verification failed.
To git@git.example.com:michaelv1234/tomcat.git
0032c02..6e8ef97  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

I have already removed the  "known_hosts" file on every servers but i'm still getting the error

Comment: Just for testing, in your git hook, can you `unset GIT_DIR`?

Comment: yes i can     unset GIT_DIR

Comment: Did it change anything?

Comment: no I have also tried with unset GIT_DIR & unset GIT_WORK_DIR, still receiving the error

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
On the Gitlab server:

```
sudo su - git
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id michael@docker.example.com
ssh michael@docker.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the SSH keys on docker.example.com change?

You're receiving the `remote: Host key verification failed.` error because the SSH host key of the docker.example.com machine does not match the key that is contained in the `known_hosts` file on git.example.com.

Search the git.example.com machine for `known_hosts` files and see if it contains an entry for `docker.example.com`. If you find an entry, delete and retry the operation (or alternatively run `ssh-keygen -R docker.example.com >> /path/to/known_hosts` to update the key for that host).

Comment: No the SSH keys didn't changed